# Generate button click event in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, button, eventhandler

I have an HTML button control and on click I want to call a asp.net button click event. I want to know how can I generate a click event handler in code behind?

when I am trying to do this in the Page_Load event:

```
 btnSearch.Click += new EventHandler();
```

I get error:

> btnSearch doesnot exist in the current context

Here is the HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="SmallButton ButtonSpacingAfter" value="Search" id="btnSearch" onserverclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to a server side control by specifying **runat="server"** .

```
<input id="foo "runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="foo_OnClick" />
```